# fire the trigger after the delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm using an `after delete` trigger, and what the trigger does is that it updates a row when another one is deleted; but the problem is, the way I update the row it gets the same key as the deleted one: but since that an `after delete` trigger keeps the supposed deleted row, and I can't update the other row because of key violation, is there any way to delete that row definitely and *then* fire the trigger (I don't need a rollback)

so this is my trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER REORDONNE
AFTER DELETE  ON TEST1_TEST2
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @oldOrder int

SELECT @oldOrder = ListOrder FROM deleted

UPDATE TEST1_TEST2
SET ListOrder=ListOrder-1
WHERE ListOrder > @oldOrder
END;
```

and my table TEST1_TEST2 is this :

[image]

The KEY of my table is (LONSId,LOId,ListOrder)

and then i execute this request :

delete from TEST1_TEST2
where NSId=13 and Id=1

the problem is when i try to delete this 4th row the trigger will try to update the 5th row and change the value of ListOrder to 1 but i get an error of KEY because these 2 rows will have the same key saying :

> Msg 2627, Niveau 14, État 1, Procédure REORDONNE, Ligne 19
>
> Violation de la contrainte UNIQUE KEY 'IX_TEST1_TEST2'. Impossible d'insérer une clé en double dans l'objet 'dbo.TEST1_TEST2'.

I hope this is clear enough

Comment: Please show us your query

Comment: There seems to be something missing from your question, can you guess what it is?

Comment: You might also want to reconsider the wording your your **statement**. One very long sentence just makes it confusing and difficult to read.

Comment: Share table structure, sample data, expected result and your work so far.

Comment: i did and hope it is more clear

Comment: Aside from anything else, your trigger is broken since it assumes that `deleted` contains exactly one row (by assigning a value from it to a scalar variable). In fact, `deleted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows.

Comment: Images of data aren't helpful (especially when it's so small). Post it in a consumable format. Have a look at [Forum Etiquette: How to post data for a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Comment: yeah thank you , but the fact that i have 0 or 1 or multiple rows in deleted is not the problem here, i jut wanna know if there is a way to delete the row completely before i do my update

Comment: The row *is* deleted. Therefore,you're currently *misdiagnosing* the issue. I've not determined a definite error path relating to ignoring multiple rows (other than that `ListOrder` values will *not* be contiguous, which is presumably the objective of this trigger in the first place) which is why it was only offered as a comment currently.

Comment: i think that the source of the error is tha fact that at some point i have 2 rows with the same key,t he row i want to delete and the row that i update bacause when i change SET ListOrder=ListOrder-1 to SET ListOrder=10 i get no error, because the column ListOrder wont be the same in this case, i heard that the delete is not commited until the execution of the trigger is valid. I'm sure about why it does this andi'm looking for a way to commit the delete before the update or somrthing like that

Comment: Is `ListOrder` a unique key? Maybe consider removing that constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to renumber *all* rows with a higher `ListOrder` column value than one of the deleted rows - not just those that share the same `LONSId` and `LOId` values<sup>1</sup>. So we need to tighten up the `UPDATE` to better target it.

Whilst we're at it, we may as well make the trigger multi-row-delete correct too:

```
CREATE TRIGGER REORDONNE
AFTER DELETE  ON TEST1_TEST2
AS
BEGIN
;With Ranges as (
    select
        LONSId,
        LOId,
        ListOrder,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY LONSId,LOId ORDER BY ListOrder) as Cnt,
        LAG(ListOrder) OVER (PARTITION BY LONSId,LOId ORDER BY ListOrder desc)
                  as NextListOrder
    from
        deleted
)
update t
set ListOrder= t.ListOrder- Cnt
from
    TEST1_TEST2 t
        inner join
    Ranges r
        on
            t.LONSId = r.LONSId and
            t.LOId = r.LOId and
            t.ListOrder > r.ListOrder and
            (r.NextListOrder is null or r.NextListOrder > t.ListOrder)
END;
```

Hopefully the logic here is clear. We work out which rows which still exist in the table should be affected by each row from `deleted` and make sure that we only target those rows, considering the *entire* key.

(If your version of SQL Server doesn't support `LAG` then a simple search of SO should find plenty of examples for faking it on older versions. If it doesn't support `ROW_NUMBER` or `CTE`s then you may be able to fake those but really, it's beyond time to upgrade from such machines).

---

<sup>1</sup>E.g. in your example, `delete from TEST1_TEST2 where NSId=13 and Id=1`, your trigger will try to update all rows with a `ListOrder` greater than `1`. The actual conflict you're being told about (or at least one of them) is for the row with current key (2,2,2) which is *also* affected by your update statement, but (2,2,1) wasn't the row that was deleted and so that's the duplicate key value.

Comment: ohhhhhh thank you sooo much you're a life saver. And thank you for the multi-row-delete correct too that's soo nice.

Comment: @omarbezzanou - I do *hope* that you take the time to consider and learn from this situation. I suggested that you were misdiagnosing the situation but you seemed to be adamant that you understood the situation and only needed help with "really deleting" rows when in fact no such situation pertained. When troubleshooting, challenge *all* of your assumptions, and don't, necessarily, dismiss other's doubts.